# Visual Studio and QT rights?

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I want to make small programs for my father company(small company).I want to make his life easier by making small programs for everything he needs(mostly DATABASE MANAGMENT or SCHEDULE MANAGEMENT).I want to program in c++ using visual studio and qt for user interface. But I only have the community visual studio edition and the free qt edition. I am allowed to make programs for his company even thought I didn't buy those software?(qt and visual studio)

Note:The programs will only be used by him! not by his employees.

Comment: If you never publish the code or give it to anyone else to use, the GPL license for the free addition does not require you to release it, I believe.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1492956/4131059

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using GPL 3rd party code for internal closed source project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492687/using-gpl-3rd-party-code-for-internal-closed-source-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please note that this is a technical forum, not a legal forum.

Anyway here are some elements to think about:

### Qt

Qt is available for free under the LGPLv3 or the GPLv3. That means that you can do whatever you want with Qt as long as you comply either with one or the other.

GPL

In practice, it means that if you distribute the application you must also distribute your source code.

LGPLv3

If you distribute the application, you must provide a way for end users to relink against a modified version of Qt. If you use dynamic linking it simply means that the user shall be able to change the Qt dll (or .so) files. But you have to keep in mind that not all Qt modules are available under LGPL, some are published only under the GPL. (https://www.qt.io/licensing-comparison/)

For your case, it seems that you are not going to distribute the application so you do not really care.

### Visual Studio Community

On the [website](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) we have:

> #### For organizations
>
> An unlimited number of users within an organization
>   can use Visual Studio Community for the following scenarios: in a
>   classroom learning environment, for academic research, or for
>   contributing to open source projects.
>
> For all other usage scenarios:
>   In non-enterprise organizations, up to five users can use Visual
>   Studio Community. In enterprise organizations (meaning those with >250
>   PCs or >$1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue), no use is permitted
>   beyond the open source, academic research, and classroom learning
>   environment scenarios described above.

So basically either you must make your apps open source or your father's company should not have more than 250 PCs or make more that 1 million $ a year.

If you are not illegible your could use:

- IDE:

  - Visual Studio Express (but does not support Qt plugins and the 2017 version is not available)
  - Qt Creator
  - any IDE that support qmake or cmake projects
- Compiler

  - MinGW (provided in the Qt Online installer)
  - Visual C/C++ compiler (provided as part of Visual Studio or as a standalone as "Build Tools for Visual Studio")